# Are there any languages that are not written in c++, rust, or ada?

Tags: oop, go

I am currently developing a programming language for which I am using golang as a primary programming language.

It doesn't seem much slower than python. 
I just wanted to know that whether I am wasting my time writing language in go?
Has anyone already written any programming language keeping golang as base language?

I hear that the fastest languages are c, c++, rust, and ada. I also heard that go was fast, but not nearly as fast as c++. What (semi-popular) languages are written in go, or any other non-ultra fast programming language.

Comment: See [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/267086/is-every-language-written-in-c) on the Software Engineering Stack site.

Comment: Are you writing a *compiled* or *interpreted* language? If it's compiled, it doesn't matter what language the compiler is written in (it'll only affect compilation speed).

Comment: It is interpreted

Comment: Languages aren't written in anything; interpreters and compilers can be written for any language, *in* any language.

Comment: I have googled a bit found this repo: https://github.com/goby-lang/goby

Comment: You seem to ignore C, or conflate C and C++; but they really are two different languages. Few popular (let alone fast) compilers are written in C++, compared to C.

Answer (score 1):

you can check this book when writing a language based on Go: [Writing An Interpreter In Go](https://interpreterbook.com/). It also has a sequel , [Writing A Compiler In Go](https://compilerbook.com/).

It shows the development of a toy language called monkey, and while monkey is not being used in production, the book does a good job of showing the fundamentals. You can read more about it on their website.

There is a particular language that is being developed by [Alexander Medvednikov](https://github.com/medvednikov), which is [vlang](https://vlang.io/).
Vlang aims to be a production ready language, so also check it out. Vlang was initially developed in Go, but now it's compiler is in vlang, which is another example of bootstrapping.

If you count Domain specific languages, you can argue that Dockerfile format is also written in Go, as docker daemon is in Go, and it has to parse Dockerfile.

Well, Golang is also written in Golang. The language had a compiler in C until version 1.4, but they rewrote their compiler in Golang, compiled it with the old C compiler, and use their Golang compiler since the said version. That thing is called bootstrapping, and is a popular way when developing new languages.

If I'm right, the language that the compiler is written only affect the compile time of the language, and the runtime speed is affected by your optimizations on the compiler itself. (Assuming you have a compiled language).

For interpreted languages, which you seem to have, because you compare yours with python, Golang might be slower than C++, although keep in mind that this is the case if you can optimize both languages pretty well.( which is a hard thing to do)

I think, it's not a waste of time to develop a language in Go. It's easier to develop than C++ (again, my opinion) , thus you can iterate quickly while developing the semantics of your own language. If you end up requiring much more speed than Go can offer, good for you, that means your language is popular now, and has a stable syntax, you can think of rewriting it in Rust, or C. Until than, Go should be fine.

Comment: Vlang is not developped "by go" (??) but rather it was initially developped in Go. It has then been rewritten in Vlang language, such that it is now a self compiler.

Comment: @a427 I added that information to the answer. I think vlang is a great example for this question. Compile time is very fast, thus provides quick feedback to language developer. When it was go-based, this was also true for the compiler, since go compiles much faster than c, c++ and rust.